# Determining if one row's column equals another row's column

Tags: sql-server

Hello I a table like this:

```
ID | Name | Description | Location | Effec_Dte
----------------------------------------------
1  | Serv | OHCOD01     | NYNY     | 2014-1-1
2  | Serv | OHCOD01     | CALA     | 2014-1-1
3  | Serv | OHCOA11     | SCCO     | 2014-5-1
4  | Serv | OHCOA11     | SCCO     | 2014-5-1
...
```

In this example there are two applications, one hosted in New York AND LA
the other is hosted in only Columbia. I want to find each application and check the first and second row to determine if they are in the same city or they are hosted in two different cities.

Is there a way to do this?

thanks!

EDIT:

```
SELECT NAME FROM TABLE
WHERE (//Logic to find all names that exist in two locations)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Belong to two or more different cities

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Location  ORDER BY ID ) AS Row
    FROM Mytable
) 
where CTE.Row>1
```

Belong to Only 1 cities

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Location  ORDER BY ID ) AS Row
    FROM Mytable
) 
where CTE.Row=1
```

Comment: I am not sure how to incorporate this into my query... does this go in a where clause?

Comment: You just need to fire above sql with your table name